# Ubuntu stuck at spinning logo at boot time

Tags: boot, nvidia

I am about to give up.  Reinstalled 3 time 20.04 LTS for same reason which is that my system stuck at spinning logo.  System works super fine for a while after each install and this seems to happen after my computer is turned off for some consecutive days.  Like more that 4 days.  (busy working)  There is not keyboard respond, no grub menu possible.  I will reinstalled one last time but would like read anyone that fixed this.  DELL precision M6600 with NVIdia Quadro (generic driver). thanks

Comment: Interesting.  On my legacy boot setup I have cd-rom first and SSD second.  with no bootable image in cd-rom system should boot to ssd.  Before reinstalled i just changed the order and put SSD first.  To my surprise it fixed my issue and now I get passed the spinning logo.  usually if there is not bootable image on cd-rom the system goes automatically to second in the list.  Is this a known ubuntu bug or i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

your problem described is a bit broad, to be sure, I assume you can access your BIOS but Ubuntu can't load grub, so you get a black screen, a first good idea would be to check some common solutions like the ones described here

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-ubuntu-linux-pc-wont-boot/

but coming back to answering your question. What I would try before reinstalling is boot from a live media Ubuntu (CD or USB) and follow this steps

https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

I hope it's useful, if it doesn't work or gain insight on the problem you should add it as a comment.

Comment: thanks.  Same... will try another distro will see what happens

Comment: Fixed!  Experienced same symptomes with CentOS.  Boot hanging before login 4 times out of 6 for no apparent reasons.  So i decided to force default settings to BIOS and now works great for a week so problem solve.  although the only settings i temperd with is the boot order mainly for testing.  so i guess forcing default setting on a 2014 machine when you experience bizarre boot issues might be a good thing to do.